# Bootstrap: delete confirmation modal don't working

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create a delete-confirmation-modal but it doesn't work.
When I click on the image in the delete column nothing happens.

I want that when I click on this image a window opens where I can choose whether to close it or to delete the record.

Here my code:

```js
<div class="panel-body">
      <table class="table table-hover table-sm">
        <thead class="thead-light">
          <tr>
            <th>Code</th>
            <th>Surname</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let customer of customers">
            <td> <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" (click)="openModal(editProfileModal, customer)" > {{customer.code}} </button></td>
            <td>{{customer.surname}}</td> 
            <td>{{customer.name}}</td>
            <td>  <a href="#myModal" class="trigger-btn" data-toggle="modal"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/ba/Red_x.svg" width="15" height="20"></a> </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody><br>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-confirm">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header flex-column">
              
          <h4 class="modal-title w-100">Are you sure?</h4>  
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Do you really want to delete this records? This process cannot be undone.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer justify-content-center">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="deleteCustomer(customer.code)">Delete</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two mistakes in your html code.

1. First you have extra closing `div` tag.
2. Second you can't use `<br>` tag as a nested element in `table` tag.

[image]

Comment: i tried but it still doesn't work. A little doubt is arising in me; is it not that I am wrong to put the code of <div id = "myModal ...> immediately after the declaration of the button?

Comment: Please put your code on stackblitz to debug better

Answer (score 0):

This may help

```
<td>  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/ba/Red_x.svg" width="15" height="20" (click)="deleteOption(args)"> </td>
```

In ts File =>

```
deleteOption=(args)=>{
let result = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete");
if (result){
//DO DELETION
}
else{
//DONT DELETE
}
}
```